# Loading another page into DIV and refreshing every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript

I am using the below to load a form into a div.

```
<script>
$("#TheForm").load("Form.php"); 
</script>
```

How can I amend this script to load the content (refresh it) every 5 seconds?

Comment: use `setInterval` and loads it after `5000ms`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setInterval`, Like this:

```
$("#TheForm").load("Form.php"); // For first time
setInterval(() => {
  $("#TheForm").load("Form.php");
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about loading it first time instantly, then every 5 secs?

Comment: @Vogal `$("#TheForm").load("Form.php");` before `setInterval` also to run it instantly as soon as the script runs.